solana-test-validator: Unable to detect Rocks columns error
Super new to programming with Solana, please pardon my noob-ness.
I'm trying to run solana-test-validator --log , but I keep getting this error:
...
[2024-09-06T22:18:06.427547000Z INFO  solana_ledger::blockstore] Opening blockstore at "test-ledger/rocksdb"
[2024-09-06T22:18:06.429522000Z WARN  solana_ledger::blockstore_db] Unable to detect Rocks columns: Error { message: "IO error: No such file or directory: While opening a file for sequentially reading: test-ledger/rocksdb/CURRENT: No such file or directory" }
...

illegal hardware instruction  solana-test-validator --log
Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Thanks!

Works for me on mac. What os are you on? Do you have write access in the folder you are running it?

Yea I do have access. I do see the rocksdb folder too, so I find it weird that it says Unable to detect Rocks columns: Error...
I'm running M1 Max and on Sonoma 14.6.1 .


illegal hardware instruction  solana-test-validator --log

The error suggests that you have binaries for the incorrect platform. Be sure that you're using the aarch64 macos builds, ie solana-release-aarch64-apple-darwin.tar.bz2 from https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/releases/tag/v2.0.8

The Unable to detect message is a warning log. That message is getting emitted because RocksDB is trying to open an instance at the ledger path, but can't find anything. This is not a fatal error, RocksDB just creates a new instance in this case.
As Jon C already mentioned, I suspect your binary to be incompatible with your system
